# Can't build using MacPorts in OS X

Tags: macos, unix, xcode, macports, llvm

I've submitted a ticket [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/44280), but I am pretty pessimistic it'll be addressed. As I say, there, I'm running [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) 2.3.1 on OS X 10.9.3. In trying to install llvm-3.2, I get the following error:

```
-->  Computing dependencies for llvm-3.2
--->  Building llvm-3.2
Error: org.macports.build for port llvm-3.2 returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port llvm-3.2 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_llvm-3.2/llvm-3.2/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port llvm-3.2 failed
```

I've looked up various help threads on the Internet, and some people recommend cleaning via

```
port clean --all all
sudo port -f uninstall inactive
```

but this doesn't seem to have done anything. I believe I'm running the newest [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).

Is there a way to figure out what is wrong with the build process? I'm not even sure where to start! The log file can be found [here](https://trac.macports.org/attachment/ticket/44280/main.log). I am running Xcode version 5.1.1 (5B1008) with command line tools installed.

Comment: **We need the log file.**  What version of XCode are you running, so other people, can verify what version is the current version.

Comment: @Ramhound : I added a link to the log file, and I'm running XCode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008). Thanks.